# django-socketio: No attribute 'response_headers_list'

Tags: python, django, django-socketio

I'm not able to run the django-socketio example project.
The error is:

> AttributeError: 'SocketIOHandler' object has no attribute 'response_headers_list'

trying to establish the socket connection.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio/issues/63) it seems I have to downgrade some packages.

But can't install `gevent: 0.13.6` and `gevent-websocket: 0.2.3`

using pip, I get the following messages:

```
Downloading/unpacking gevent==0.13.6
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gevent

  Requested gevent==0.13.6, but installing version 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**wtong2** has found **working configuration** for django 1.5.5 and 1.6
Look to [that issue](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio/issues/63)

Example of my requirements.txt according to his aswer next:

django==1.5.5 
django-socketio==0.3.6 
gevent-socketio==0.2.1 
gevent-websocket==0.2.3 
gevent==0.13.6

Thanks to wtong2

Comment: Still not working with the current regular `pip install` (with Django 1.6)